# MonetDB SELECT query slow when we don't add single quote in where clause

Tags: monetdb

I have a table around 1.5TB,  with 23 billion records.  When I try to get the number of rows for a specific date,  it takes around 30 mins if the date is not enclosed in single quotes,  but takes 2 mins if it is.  The date field is of type `DECIMAL(8)`

This query takes 2 mins:

```
select count(*) from rwow where date = '20160222';
```

But this one takes 30 mins:

```
select count(*) from rwow where date = 20160222;
```

They both return the same result.  Could someone help me understand why this is?

Comment: Please profile both versions of your query by prefixing them with key-word TRACE and share the profiling output to help us understand where the time goes. Then, we might understand why.
Thanks!
Stefan